# Error in .each execution (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I'm making an auditor with ruby which started off fine this morning (using single word, user inputted content to omit) but now that I've tried to implement a wordlist, it `puts` the string to search through as many times as there are words in the wordlist, only censoring it once or twice. My code is as follows.

```
#by Nightc||ed, ©2015
puts "Enter string: "
text = gets.chomp
redact = File.read("wordlist.txt").split(" ")
words = text.split(" ")
redact.each do |beep|
    words.each do |word|
        if word != beep
            print word + " "
        else
            print "[snip] "
        end
    end
end
sleep
```

I kind of understand why it doesn't work but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way than iterating through each array. The `Array#include` method can be easily used to see if the word is contained in your redacted list.

Here's some code that should behave how you wanted the original code to behave:

```
puts "Enter string: "
text = gets.chomp
redact = File.read("wordlist.txt").split(" ")
words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |word|
  if redact.include? word
    print "[snip] "
  else
    print word + " "
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrubbing text gets very tricky. One thing you want to watch out for is word boundaries. Splitting on spaces will let a lot of beep words get through because of puctuation. Compare the first two results of the sample code below.

Next, assembling the split text back into its intended form with punction, spacing, etc., gets to be quite challenging. You may want to consider using regex for something presuambly as small as user comments. See the third result.

If you're doing this as a learning exercise, great, but if the application is sensitive where you're likely to take heat over failures to bleep words, you may want to look for an existing well-tested library.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Bleeper

scifi_curses = ['friggin', 'gorram', 'fracking', 'dork']
text = "Why splitting spaces won't catch all the friggin bleeps ya gorram, fracking dork."

words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |this_word|
  puts "bleep #{this_word}" if scifi_curses.include?(this_word)
end

puts

better_words = text.split(/\b/)
better_words.each do |this_word|
  puts "bleep #{this_word}" if scifi_curses.include?(this_word)
end

puts

bleeped_text = text # keep copy of original if needed
scifi_curses.each do |this_curse|
  bleeped_text.gsub!(this_curse, '[bleep]')
end

puts bleeped_text
```

You should get these results:

```
bleep friggin
bleep fracking

bleep friggin
bleep gorram
bleep fracking
bleep dork

Why splitting spaces won't catch all the [bleep] bleeps ya [bleep], [bleep] [bleep].
```